# Oppo mobile blocks button clicks with hyperlink

Tags: applications, apk

I have developed an android app, which has a button that opens a website link on click. The function works in Motorola, Samsung, some Redmi phones.But, the function doesn't works on oppo phones. Button click to load new activity(pages/app window)works well. What may be the reason? Its not development related question. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Taking a log of what happens when you click and adding that to question may help

Comment: I have done that, it shows arrayoutofbounds error in oppo only, the function works well on my motorola and samsung mobiles (no error)

Comment: Wild guess - is that Oppo phone rooted with EdXposed? If yes, uninstall EdXposed and check. I had encountered this error in a different context, when no array was called for and it turned out to be EdXposed created problem

Comment: Does this also happen on other apps? Otherwise, I assume [this is the relevant code on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292761/arrayoutofbounds-while-manupulationg-sms-data), which might as well a device-dependent development issue. Some vendors are "brave" enough to customize their Android framework and making it fragmented even for developers.